# animateWithDuration not working correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I have written some code that I had hoped would randomly spin a block into view on the screen, pause, then spin it out.  The action should repeat itself in a semi random fashion.  This kinda of works in that it shows the block, spins out, then shows itself again after some time however:

- It does not spin in (it only spins out)
- It never changes position

What vital thing am I missing from this code?

```
-(void)randomlyShowBlock{
    int randomTime = 1 + arc4random() % (3 - 1);

    [RandomBlock setNeedsDisplay];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, randomTime * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        int randomX = 10 + arc4random() % ((int)self.view.frame.size.width - 10);
        int randomY = 10 + arc4random() % ((int)self.view.frame.size.height - 10);

        RandomBlock.frame = CGRectMake(randomX, randomY, RandomBlock.frame.size.width, RandomBlock.frame.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^(void) {
                             RandomBlock.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(-90));
                             RandomBlock.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:124.0/255.0 blue:203.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                              animations:^(void) {
                                                  RandomBlock.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(0));
                                                  RandomBlock.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:0];
                                              }
                                              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                  NSLog(@"finished animation");
                                                  //model

                                                  [self randomlyShowBlock];
                                              }];
                         }];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the frame in the animation, so it's not surprising that it's not moving.

As for the spinning, my guess is that the transform is not initially an identity transform, but rather a nil one, and iOS doesn't know how to animate from nothing to something.  Try setting it, before the animation block, to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Comment: I want it to move behind the scenes, and then transform.. Ill try setting CGAffineTransformIdentity before hand see how that works though :) - just checked and doesnt work mate